# Collapsible interesting/ignored tags sections

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I have added pretty many ignored tags, so the relevant section on the right side is quite large.  In fact, it is so large that question page vertical size is usually determined by the right auxiliary column, not by the main contents.  This creates a large empty space gap between question list and page links (prev/1/2/.../next) and forces additional scrolling.

Request: please make interesting/ignored tags sections collapsible, preferably with collapsed state remembered across pages, so that ignored tags list doesn't make pages unnecessary long.

Comment: Give a mouse a cookie? And then the `Recent-Tags` section and then `Recent-Badges` and then and then ... all the other sidebar sections.

Comment: It is a bit ironic to have your screen taken over by *ignored* tags

Answer (score 6):

I'll second this. That'd be a useful feature.

Remembering collapse state might be more trouble than it's worth, however. I'd say make them collapsed be default, always, with an expansion only a click away.

Comment: I third this and +1 for faster page loads without inconsistent behavior across logged in machines.

Answer (score 5):

I had same idea. I also prepared a mock-up! Check it out: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Please make something with that, I have over 100+ ignors and it destroys me viewing SO.

I've created a user script to collapsing it for now, but please have this feature in mind.

[Stack Ignore Collapse .user.js](http://hrabstwo.net/hornet/js/stackignorecollapse.user.js)

Also posted on StackApps as a script:

[Collapse interesting and ignored tags sections!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2470/collapse-interesting-and-ignored-tags-sections)

Answer (score 2):

We will be implementing this this week.  Ignored tags will be collapsed to one line with an ellipsis button to expand.

This is now live on all sites.

[image]