# Tag list collapsed - Highlight no longer works

Tags: bug, status-completed, ignored-tags, tag-highlighting

So, on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), I have a rather long list of favorite and ignored tags. Usually, that just makes the page ridiculously long and increases the time the highlighting takes.

Well, after the change to [collapse tag lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188913/) rolled out, my ignored tags are collapsed - and suddenly only the first couple of tags end up getting faded out. Turns out, only the first get the `tagged-ignored` class applied.

I guess that's not intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, totally unintended. With hiding some of the ignored tags, the jQuery selector that was used for hiding/fading them was no longer correct and I missed that.

Fixed in the next build (2013.7.17.855).

Comment: I assumed as much. :D

Comment: Yeah, blame jQuery! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not sure if it's a not enough or too much ;)

Comment: There's no such thing as "too much" when blaming jQuery.

Comment: Which revision is that fixed in? I still see issues with 2013.7.17.854...

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: @RowlandShaw - it will be in 2013.7.17.855

Comment: @J.Steen blocked by my firewall at least...

Comment: @RowlandShaw Under what rule? It's a normal gif, from a blog, somewhere on the internet. Maybe your firewall doesn't like jQuery.

Comment: @J.Steen Blame WebSense - it's not good enough to tell me why it blocked it, nor does there appear to be anyway for blocked sites to query their database, but that's [another rant](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/3804/1918)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Ah. Sorry. =/

Comment: @RowlandShaw - thanks for the edit. How's your ignored list looking like now?

Comment: @Oded Yay. Awesomeness ensues (i.e. it's fixed :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw - GR8... Glad no edge cases were discovered ;)